# Question about Australia ETA and before enter to Australia

Tags: us-citizens, australia, eta, criminal-records

I will travel to Australia to visit my relative next 6 more days. When I filled the application for ETA, has a question: Has the applicant ever had a criminal conviction? I ticked NO ( by mistake) and actually I had a conviction almost 6 years ago for theft of property $500 or less with the arrested 1 day and 11 months 28 days on probation (misdemeanor) . I granted the Australia ETA now.

My question is that even I said NO on the application but Australia still checked my criminal record then gave me ETA?

What about before I enter to Australia, they will give a Incoming Passenger Card (IPC) to fill out, it has question: Do you have any criminal conviction? What am I going to tick, YES or NO, if I say YES it conflict with NO on the ETA application and what they will do?

I really need advises on my situation, please be advised as soon as you can.

Comment: They didn't check your criminal record.  If they had, they would have denied the ETA for misrepresentation.

Comment: You’re in something of a catch-22 situation. Telling the truth in the IPC could get you denied entry and maybe a ban for misrepresentation. *Not* telling the truth means you’ll probably have to continue with the lie every time you fill out pretty much any immigration form that asks this question in future. Bear in mind that the US, UK, Australia, Canada, and N Zealand share intelligence amongst themselves and with other countries http://privacyinternational.org/learn/five-eyes You can take a chance, or you might want to consult an immigration lawyer before you start your trip

Comment: Australia apparently worry only about **substantial** criminal records, defined [here](https://immi.homeaffairs.gov.au/help-support/glossary#substantial-criminal-record). It’s not clear to me what your sentence was, though.

Comment: My sentence was 1 day jail ( arrested) and suspended sentence (probation) 11 months 28 days, considering Misdemeanor.

Comment: What is your citizenship and in what country did you get your misdemeanor conviction?

Comment: I am U.S.A citizenship and got misdemeanor in this country.